# How can I remove a column in a pandas DataFrame and make another column clickable, redirecting to a URL in the same row?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

Suppose I have a pandas DF with the below data:

```
`data = {
    'Crypto': ['ARB', 'ETH', 'ETH'],
    'Position': ['Long 10.0X', 'Short 25.0X', 'Short 2.0X'],
    'Size Crypto': ['1,075,328.5024 ARB', '20.5007 ETH', '11.937 ETH'],
    'Size USD': ['$1,240,929', '$37,225', '$21,675'],
    'Entry Price': ['$1.15', '$1,793.4', '$1,810.4'],
    'ROE': ['+ 3.94%', '- 31.24%', '- 0.60%'],
    'URL': ['www.google.com',
            'www.google.com',
            'www.google.com'],
    'Win Loss Ratio': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    'Last Price': ['1.152000', '1813.00', '1813.00']
}`
```

I would like to get rid off the 'URL' column, but make it such that the 'Crypto' column is clickable and it redirects to the corresponding value under 'URL'.

Is this possible to achieve? I can't find anything in Google or the Pandas doc.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you want to convert the dataframe to HTML table, with URL links?

Comment: If I follow you, no, I would like to preserve the dataframe, just that the value under 'Crypto' such as 'ARB' is clickable and it directs to the value under the 'URL' column @AndrejKesely

Comment: What do you mean with 'clickable'?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it :

```
(
    df.assign(Crypto= df[["Crypto", "URL"]].apply(
        lambda x: f'<a href="{x[1]}">{x[0]}</a>', axis=1))
            .drop(columns="URL")
            .style
)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Beautiful - thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension with [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) to remove the column, then either convert [`to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) or use [`style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.style.html) depending on how you want to handle the output:

```
from IPython.display import HTML  
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Crypto'] = [f'<a href="{url}">{symbol}</a>'
                for symbol, url in zip(df['Crypto'], df.pop('URL'))]

HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))

# or
df.style
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful - thanks for taking the time